# How to implement the javascript setTimeout function in Java

Tags: android, search, asynchronous, settimeout

I am currently trying to integrate a live search functionality in android. I use a customized Autocomplete widget. The widget itself provides me with a threshold to only start a query after a certain amount of characters have been typed in. But what I also want is that a query only starts, say if a user has stopped typing for 2 seconds.

As I load my contents with a `AsyncTask` I tried blocking the `doInBackground` function by calling Thread.sleep() right at the beginning. If the user would then continue typing the program would look after an existing task, cancel it and start a new one. This was my idea. But it doesn't quite work the way I expected. Sometimes it sends out queries even if the user is still typing, sometimes queries are canceled after the users stopped typing.

Do you have any ideas on this or maybe a better way to solve this?

Here are the code snippets:

**1. The function that is called on text changes:**

```
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    if(mWidget.enoughToFilter()) {
        if(mTask != null && mTask.getStatus() != Status.FINISHED) {
            mTask.cancel(true);
        }

        mTask = new KeywordSearchLoader(mActivity, 
                mItems);

        mTask.execute(s.toString());

    }
}
```

**2. doInBrackground**

```
try {
    Thread.sleep(Properties.ASYNC_SEARCH_DELAY);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    Log.e(TAG, "the process was interrupted while sleeping");
    Log.w(TAG, e);
}
```

Thanks
Phil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a `Handler` and use [`.postDelayed(..)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#postDelayed%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long%29) to run a background task after some delay.

If user presses the key then call [`handler.removeCallback(..)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#removeCallbacks%28java.lang.Runnable%29) and then again [`.postDelayed(..)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#postDelayed%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long%29) to add a new delayed callback.

Comment: That sounds like something I was looking for. I'll give it a try.

Comment: Thanks very much. Works like a charm. The only thing you have to watch out for is, that the Handler expects a runnable. So what I had to do is implement the run() method in my AsyncTask and executing `execute` in this method. Doing this I had to assure, that the object already knows the params for execute.

Comment: Do you need an `AsyncTask` in this case? Do you run it with `.execute()`?

Comment: I do need the Async task, because I want to make changes to the parent view. If I would start a new Thread, making changes to the views would give me exceptions as android does not allow this.

Comment: Yes this is what I meant. Handlers and Messages can be used in this situation: http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/faq/commontasks.html#threading